# Delete 1 line before, 1 line after a match and the line with the match

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need to edit a big size (>300mb) log file deleting lines. 
The lines to removing are the lines of the match of a string, the line before and the line after.
I have to run this bat/cmd in windows.

Example of my MASTER.log:

```
[Thu May 11 16:39:58 2017]Local/MASTER///9044/Info(1042059)
Connected from [::ffff:10.64.44.209]

[Thu May 11 16:39:58 2017]Local/MASTER/Plan2/admin@Native Directory/9044/Info(1204002)
Hybrid Aggregation Mode enabled.

[Thu May 11 16:39:58 2017]Local/MASTER/Plan2/admin@Native Directory/9044/Info(1013091)
Received Command [MdxReport] from user [admin@Native Directory]

[Thu May 11 16:39:58 2017]Local/MASTER/Plan2/admin@Native Directory/9044/Info(1204002)
Hybrid Aggregation Mode enabled.

[Thu May 11 16:39:58 2017]Local/MASTER/Plan2/admin@Native Directory/9044/Info(1204002)
Hybrid Aggregation Mode enabled.

[Thu May 11 16:39:58 2017]Local/MASTER/Plan2/admin@Native Directory/9044/Info(1260039)
MaxL DML Execution Elapsed Time : [0.019] seconds
```

I need to search every recurrence of "Hybrid Aggregation Mode enabled" and delete the match line, the line before and the line after.

The result should be:

```
[Thu May 11 16:39:58 2017]Local/MASTER///9044/Info(1042059)
Connected from [::ffff:10.64.44.209]

[Thu May 11 16:39:58 2017]Local/MASTER/Plan2/admin@Native Directory/9044/Info(1013091)
Received Command [MdxReport] from user [admin@Native Directory]

[Thu May 11 16:39:58 2017]Local/MASTER/Plan2/admin@Native Directory/9044/Info(1260039)
MaxL DML Execution Elapsed Time : [0.019] seconds
```

I tried with findstr but I can delete only the result line.

Comment: Please edit your question and use `{}` to format it. It's not at all clear where the newlines appear. Please also show your code from any attempt you have made to solve your problem, otherwise your question may be closed unanswered as a "write this code for me" request. Are you able to use 3rd-party utilities like `sed` ?

Comment: You need to try something else, expanding perhaps on the `FindStr` effort you say you tried but haven't provided in your question. We're not a free coding service that gets motivated by you getting paid for our work, you need to make some effort yourself.

Comment: So when you say the line after you mean the empty line and you want to keep the existing empty lines if there is not a match?

Answer (score 0):

Although you did not show any own efforts to solve your task, I decided to provide a small script, because it appears to be quite interesting; see all the explanatory remarks in the code (next time please share your efforts and precisely describe what you have problems with; consult the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour)):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_FILE=%~1" & rem // (path/name of file to process; use first command line argument)
set "_STR=Hybrid Aggregation Mode enabled." & rem // (string to search for)
set /A "_NUM=3" & rem // (count of lines to remove; begin counting at line before match)

rem // Initialise variables:
set /A "SKIP=1"
rem // Read file, iterate over all lines plus one, not ignoring empty lines:
for /F "delims=" %%L in ('findstr /N /R "^" "%_FILE%" ^& echo :') do (
    rem // Store current line string:
    set "LINE=%%L"
    setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    rem // Check whether current line string constitutes a match:
    set "COMP=!LINE:*:=!"
    if "!COMP!"=="!_STR!" (
        endlocal
        rem // Match encountered, hence set line skip counter:
        set /A "SKIP=_NUM"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    )
    rem // Check whether line skip counter reached zero:
    if !SKIP! gtr 0 (
        endlocal
        rem // Zero not reached, so decrement line skip counter:
        set /A "SKIP-=1"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
    ) else (
        rem // Zero reached, so return previous line string:
        echo(!PREV!
    )
    rem // Store current line string for next loop iteration:
    for /F "delims=" %%E in (^""!LINE:*:=!"^") do (
        endlocal
        set "PREV=%%~E"
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

I assumed you want whole lines to match the search string in a case-sensitive manner. If you want a different behaviour, you have to exchange the line `if "!COMP!"=="!_STR!" (` accordingly:

- for whole lines to match in a case-**in**sensitive manner, use this:

  ```cmd
  if /I "!COMP!"=="!_STR!" (
  ```
- for lines that contain the search string in a case-**in**sensitive manner, use this:

  ```cmd
  if defined COMP if not "!COMP!"=="!COMP:%_STR%=!" (
  ```

  In this case the search string `_STR` must not be empty, must not contain `=`, `!`, `"`, `^`, and must not begin with `*` or `~`.
- for lines that contain the search string in a case-sensitive manner, use this:

  ```cmd
  if defined COMP if not "!COMP!"=="!COMP:%_STR%=!" if "!COMP!"=="!COMP:%_STR%=%_STR%!" (
  ```

  In this case the same restrictions as for the previous item apply.

To use the script − let us call it `mitigate.bat` − provide the input log file as a command line argument, like this:

```cmd
mitigate.bat "MASTER.log"
```

To write the output of the script to a file, type the following (regard that input and output files must be different):

```cmd
mitigate.bat "MASTER.log" > "MASTER_mod.log"
```